# Currently using a query to order another query; can these be combined?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Right now I have a form that queries a query in order to sort it. I know it is possible to order by more than one criteria, but when I try to add the second order criteria to the query it doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the Random LP Picker query. It gives me a random selection of 10 LPs from a list of hundreds:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Artists.OriginalName, LPs.Album, LPs.rating, LPs.[Notable 
Songs], LPs.Comments, [Listened (LPs)].last_date, [Listened 
(LPs)].times_listened, LPs.LPID
FROM (LPs INNER JOIN Artists ON LPs.Performer_id = Artists.ArtistID) INNER 
JOIN [Listened (LPs)] ON LPs.LPID = [Listened (LPs)].disc_id
WHERE (((LPs.Status)=1 Or (LPs.Status)=5) AND ((LPs.[Media Type])=1))
ORDER BY Rnd(Int(Now()*[LPID])-Now()*[LPID]);
```

In my form I order the query by date like this:

```
SELECT [Random LP Picker].*
FROM [Random LP Picker]
ORDER BY [Random LP Picker].last_date;
```

I tried putting both sorts in the Random LP Picker query, so it looks like:

```
ORDER BY  Rnd(Int(Now()*[LPID])-Now()*[LPID]), [Listened (LPs)].last_date;
```

Doing that does not give me the list sorted by last_date. I also tried reversing those two sort items, but that causes several fields to not appear at all for reasons beyond my limited knowledge.

It would be useful if I could do this all in a single query. Is it possible?

NOTE: A couple of people have said, why not just order by date. The thing is, what this query is doing is randomly ordering all the entries and then returning the first 10. So if I remove the order by Rnd(...) part then I am no longer getting 10 random entries. If there's another way to get 10 random entries without using ORDER then I'd be happy to do that, but this is the only way I know to do it.

Comment: I am not sure about ms access but in general SQL orders in the order of predicates as defined i.e. from left to right. also in other rdbms angines you can define ASC or DESC e.g. ORDER BY DATE1 ASC, DATE2 DESC.

Comment: All you want for final result set to be sorted on `last_date`, hence why not just ORDER BY only on `[Listened (LPs)].last_date` in your query?

Comment: If I only order by last_date then how to I get 10 random entries? Is there another way to do that than what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving query into a derived table (i.e., subquery in `FROM`) and sort on outer query:

```
SELECT main.* 
FROM
  (SELECT TOP 10 a.OriginalName, l.Album, l.rating, l.[Notable Songs], 
          l.Comments, p.last_date, p.times_listened, l.LPID
   FROM (LPs l INNER JOIN Artists a ON l.Performer_id = a.ArtistID) 
   INNER JOIN [Listened (LPs)] p ON l.LPID = p.disc_id
   WHERE ((l.Status IN (1,5)) AND (l.[Media Type]=1))
   ORDER BY Rnd(Int(Now()*l.[LPID])-Now()*l.[LPID])
  ) As main
ORDER BY main.last_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your final result-set to be sorted on `last_date`, hence your last `ORDER BY` should be on `[Listened (LPs)].last_date`. A sub-query should return TOP 10 rows based on random numbers.

You can try replacing line 
`ORDER BY  Rnd(Int(Now()*[LPID])-Now()*[LPID]), [Listened (LPs)].last_date;`

with

`[Listened (LPs)].last_date;`

The modified query will be like:

```
    SELECT Artists.OriginalName, LPs.Album, LPs.rating, LPs.[Notable 
    Songs], LPs.Comments, [Listened (LPs)].last_date, [Listened 
    (LPs)].times_listened, LPs.LPID
    FROM (LPs INNER JOIN Artists ON LPs.Performer_id = Artists.ArtistID) INNER 
    JOIN [Listened (LPs)] ON LPs.LPID = [Listened (LPs)].disc_id
    WHERE (((LPs.Status)=1 Or (LPs.Status)=5) AND ((LPs.[Media Type])=1)) 
    AND LPs.LPID IN (SELECT TOP 10 LPID FROM LPs ORDER BY Rnd(Int(Now()*[LPID])-Now()*[LPID]))
ORDER BY [Listened (LPs)].last_date;
```

Comment: But then I won't get 10 random entries anymore; I still need that.

Comment: @CharlesHerold True. I have not modified other parts of query. I have edited it with further details.